# Is it possible to play a partial mp3 audio file as bytes gets copied in Input Stream

Tags: android, inputstream, android-mediaplayer

Two devices are connected using bluetooth. Is it possible to play a mp3 song as it is being received .
    while (fileSize >= TConstants.CHUNK_SIZE)
                {
                    int readLen = 0;
                    readLen = inputStream.read(buf, 0, TConstants.CHUNK_SIZE);
                    if (readLen < 0)
                        throw new TException(TException.EXCEPTION_READ_FILE);

```
                out.write(buf, 0, readLen);
                len += readLen;
                fileSize -= readLen;
                if (listener!=null && ((len / TConstants.CHUNK_SIZE) != prev))
                {
                    prev = len / TConstants.CHUNK_SIZE;
                    Log.d(TAG, "Chunk read " + prev + "");
                    receiverConsignment.setReadFileSize(len);
                    listener.onChunkRead(receiverConsignment);
                    // showSpinnerProgress(fileTransferModel);
                }
            }

            while (fileSize > 0)
            {
                buf = new byte[(int) fileSize];
                len = inputStream.read(buf);
                if (len < 0)
                {
                    throw new TException(TException.EXCEPTION_READ_FILE);
                }
                fileSize -= len;
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in copyFile: ", e);
            out.close();
            throw new TException(e, TException.EXCEPTION_READ_FILE);
        }
```